# The topology on a tangent bundle

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Suppose that $ M $ is an $ n $-manifold and that $ (U,\phi) $ is a chart on $ M $, where $ U $ is an open subset of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $. The claim is that
$$
  T U
= \bigsqcup_{p \in U} T_{p} U
= \bigsqcup_{p \in U} \mathbb{R}^{n}
= U \times \mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$

The identities actually mean that the objects are isomorphic as vector spaces. In [this related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143698/topology-of-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-smooth-manifold), ptF’s answer says that $ W \subseteq T M $ is open if $ {d \phi}(W \cap T U) $ is open in $ \mathbb{R}^{2 n} $, where $ d \phi: T U \to T \mathbb{R}^{n} $ is the total derivative induced by $ \phi $.

Is this well-defined? $ {d \phi}(W \cap T U) $ is a subset of $ T \mathbb{R}^{n} $, on which a topology hasn’t been defined yet. I only know that $ T \mathbb{R}^{n} $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} $ as vector spaces, but can we say that something is open in $ T \mathbb{R}^{n} $?

Comment: $ \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} $ can be given the product topology.

Comment: There is of course a topology on $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$, but my question is about the topology on $T \mathbb R^n$

Comment: That is the topology on $ T \mathbb{R}^{n} $. As $ (\mathbb{R}^{n},\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}) $ is a legitimate coordinate chart on the manifold $ M \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \mathbb{R}^{n} $, the open subsets of $ T M = T \mathbb{R}^{n} $ are, by definition, precisely the open subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} $ (with respect to the product topology).