# $\mathscr{C}^{k-1}$-manifold structure on the cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, co-tangent-space

Let $X$ be a $\mathscr{C}^k$-manifold of dimension $n$ and atlas $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ (*i.e.* its atlas is such that the transitions maps $\varphi_\beta\circ\varphi_\alpha^{-1}$ are $\mathscr{C}^k$).

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1120324/259363), we endowed the tangent bundle $TX$ with a $\mathscr{C}^{k-1}$-manifold structure of dimension $2n$. I re-did the proof entirely to make sure I had everything correct in my mind. Now, I'm onto the cotangent bundle.

I looked in the book the answer adviced (*W. D. Curtis & F. R. Miller, Differential manifolds*), and I noticed a few things :

- This time, they work with *smooth* manifolds, and therefore end up proving that $T^\ast X$ is a *smooth* manifold of dimension $2n$.
- The notations used seem a little strange. They mix up subscript and superscript asterisks, which confuses me quite a lot. I kept writing the pushforward with a subscript asterisk, whereas they sometimes seem to use it for linear maps between dual spaces (that they denote using superscript asterisks...).

I'm unsure where to continue my research, I cannot find lots of data about this, since everyone either 1) works with *smooth* manifolds, or 2) don't even bother and *assume* that $T^\ast X$ is a manifold.

I was lucky enough to have some previous lecture notes about the $\mathscr{C}^{k-1}$-manifold structure on the tangent bundle, but in these lectures, the cotangent bundle was completely avoided and differential forms were defined as *formal objects*, meaning I have no support about this.

I am in hope that a similar result holds, mainly that $T^\ast X$ has $\mathscr{C}^{k-1}$-regularity.

### Can anyone give me hints about what to do ?

Are there references dealing with this subject ?

(One last note perhaps : I defined the tangent space algebraically, *i.e.* with operators acting on locally-$\mathscr{C}^1$ real-valued functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \mapsto \varphi_i \varphi_j^{-1}x$ are the transition functions of your atlas of $M$, then the transition functions of $TM$ are $$(x,y) \mapsto (\varphi_i \varphi_j^{-1}x, \text{Jac}(\varphi_i \varphi_j^{-1})y).$$

The Jacobian is a matrix of first partials, so because $\varphi_i \varphi_j^{-1}$ is a $C^k$ function, the function above is a $C^{k-1}$ function. It seems you are already comfortable with this point.

Now the atlas on the cotangent bundle has transition functions given by $$(x,y) \mapsto (\varphi_i \varphi_j^{-1} x, \left(\text{Jac}\left(\varphi_i \varphi_j)^{-1}\right)^T\right)y).$$ The inversion and transposition operations are smooth, so again these transition functions are $C^{k-1}$.

Comment: So if I understand, if $(U,\varphi)$ is a chart on $M$, $(V,\psi)$ is a chart on $TM$ by letting $V=\pi^{-1}(U)$ and $\psi(p,\xi)=(\varphi(p),\text{d}_p\varphi(\xi))$. Now if $f:E\to F$ is a linear map, then $f^\vee:F^\vee\to E^\vee$ is the dual map (or the transpose), and this construction lets us define a chart $(W,\theta)$ on $T^\ast M$ by letting $W=(\pi^\ast)^{-1}(U)$ and $\theta(p,\chi)=(\varphi(p),(\text{d}_p\varphi)^\vee(\chi))$ ?

Comment: There must be something I'm getting wrong : $\theta(p,\chi)$ has a meaning if $\chi\in T_p^\ast X$, but it turns out $(\text{d}_p\varphi)^\vee:(\mathbb{R}^n)^\vee\to T_p^\ast X$, and not $(\text{d}_p\varphi)^\vee:T_p^\ast X\to(\mathbb{R}^n)^\vee$...

Comment: Okay, nevermind, it turns out what you wrote helped me understand what they did in the book I mentionned in my question. It turns out the chart is defined as : $\theta(p,\chi)=(\varphi(p),([\text{d}_p\varphi]^{-1})^\vee(\chi))$. Thanks !