# Different Topologies for a Tangent Bundle $TM$ of a smooth manifold $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I am following the comment of Dylan Moreland for this thread: [Topology of the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143698/topology-of-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-smooth-manifold).

I was trying to understand, why putting a disjoint union topology on $TM=\sqcup_{p\in M}T_pM$ is not a good idea? In what way different tangents spaces are not going to behave nicely?

Comment: If $TM$ had this disjoint union topology, then $M \hookrightarrow TM$ (seen as the zero section) would be discrete (!)

Comment: In fact, the projection $TM\to M$ would not admit any continuous sections, so there would not be any vector fields. Also for connected $M$, $TM$ would have uncountably many connected componts, hence is not second countable and so on.

Comment: @IvoTerek, oh, that makes sense! So, that's why we defined topology on $TM$ using the open charts of original manifold $M$?

Comment: @Andreas Cap, I tried to convince myself that the projection $TM\to M$ would not admit any continuous sections. But, I failed. Is it the same to say that there is no continuous map $\sigma:M\to TM$ such that $\pi\circ\sigma=id$?

Comment: @eightc What you wrote is exactly the definition of a continuous section

Comment: @Didier, yep, I got it, but how to show that the projection map $TM\to M$ would not admit any continuous section if $TM$ is equipped with disjoint union topology?

Comment: It $\sigma : M \to TM$ is continuous and $M$ is connected, it takes value in a connected component of $TM$. Hence, in only one fiber if you use the disjoint topology. Therefore, $\pi \circ \sigma$ is constant.